# Can I have multiple concurrent Gravatars associated with the same email address?

Tags: avatar, gravatar

If I use the same email address to register at several sites that use Gravatar, is there a way to specify a different avatar for each site? Or do I have to use a different email address for each site?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With Gravatar you just add a new email to your account using sub-addressing and set up a new image attached with each of the different versions of the same email address.

E.g. Your base email address is **user@example.com**, with sub-addressing, this can become any of the following:

- user+lifehacker@example.com
- user+candystand@example.com
- user+keepfearalive@example.com

Set those up in Gravatar and use them to register for the various sites.

If you're using an email provider that allows sub-addressing (or [plus-addressing if you're familiar with Gmail](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2008/03/2-hidden-ways-to-get-more-from-your.html)) **and** the site you register at allows you to use an email address with sub-addressing, this will definitely work.

Some sites will consider an [email with a plus as invalid](http://www.jacobsen.no/anders/blog/archives/2002/08/24/email_addresses_with_a_are_valid.html), so this won't work for them.