# Setting Gravatar images to same by disregarding any plus addressing in emails

Tags: gravatar

How can I set up Gravatar to use the same image for any plus or tagged email address used?

I have subscribed to websites such as Stack Exchange, Stack Overflow, Github, etc. using a "+" email address ([tagged email address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Address_tags)), like this one: `joeuser+stackoverflow@example.com`.

In order to display a picture with my profile, such websites rely on the **gravatar.com** service. I don't want to subscribe for every site to a new gravatar account.

Is there a possibility to have a single gravatar account linked with "+"'d email addresses?

Actually, my question is exactly the opposite of trying to [set up multiple gravatars with the same email address](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/8569/can-i-have-multiple-concurrent-gravatars-associated-with-the-same-email-address/8572#8572).

**Github** solved this problem in adding a field "*Gravatar email*" in the [Profile page](https://github.com/settings/profile). Can Stack Exchange network do the same? Where should I ask?

Comment: I couldn't find a way to do it on the website so I emailed gravatar support.

Comment: Update: I still haven't received a response to my gravatar support email.

Comment: If you want to request a Stack Exchange feature to have a "gravatar email", the best place to ask is [metase].

Answer (score 4):

Five years later, but you can now (and for quite some time) add additional email addresses to your Gravatar account. Just log in to your account, add the email address, click the link in the confirm email and you are done.

Still not as easy an practical as a "+" wildcard, but quite doable.

Comment: That would seem to be what the Asker is trying to avoid, i.e., creating a new email address for every site.

Comment: No, he said "I don't want to subscribe for every site to a new gravatar account.". Now you only have 1 gravatar account and can add a list of multiple email adresses in there.

Comment: Hmmm...I think you're right. I've only ever used Gravatar when you could already add multiple email addresses to a single account. I wasn't aware that it wasn't always that way.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like something Gravatar has not really taken into account. Based on the layout of the website there isn't a way to do this currently. You will have to find a way to contact Gravatar for a feature request.